# Async / await on addEventListener not working (bad syntax?)

Tags: javascript, forms, async-await

Novice question here - apologies if this is pure PIBCAK.

I had a problem today with an async function, where the `await` did not wait for the `fetch` to be resolved.

This is an example of the code I had an issue with:

```
form.addEventListener('submit', async (event) => {
   event.preventDefault(event);
   response = await fetch('/example',{
      method:'POST',
      body:data
   });
   console.log(response.json());
});
```

The `console.log()` in the above scenario did not wait for the fetch to complete. but instead gave me the pending promise and not the json response.

This code fixed the issue:

```
form.addEventListener('submit', async (event) => {
   event.preventDefault(event);
   response = await call();
   console.log(response.json());
});

async function call() {
   response = await fetch('/example',{
      method:'POST',
      body:data
   });
   return response.json();
```

But this seems redundant, and I still don't understand what I was doing wrong in the first place.
Is this a syntax issue ? Or is there something more basic I'm missing ?

Comment: Both `fetch()` *and* `response.json()` return a promise. You need to `await` both. (Unless you return a promise from an async function. You don't need to await that one.)

Comment: Your second version just does an extra `await` in a very roundabout way. The actual problem is simply that you did `console.log(response.json())` instead of `console.log(await response.json())`, as the `.json` function is also asynchronous!

Comment: @Ivar "You don't need to await that one." << true, but I recommend doing it anyway, for consistency and the [reasons I explained here](https://github.com/standard/standard/issues/1442).